# react-testing-library test optimization - screen.findByText vs expect(screen.findByText).toBeInTheDocument()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

In our project we do a lot of

`expect(await screen.findByText('sample text')).toBeInTheDocument()`

`expect(await screen.findByTestId('sample test id')).toBeInTheDocument()`

And recently an argument was made that we can do this instead

`await screen.findByText('sample text')`

`await screen.findByTestId('sample test id')`

because if there is no element found the test will fail anyway. We also found a small and possibly inconsistent and irrelevant improvement of run speed of a test with this change

My question is: will our tests be faster and more resource efficient if we remove all those expect calls wherever possible?

Comment: I think only you can answer this question, since your test running environment is known only to you.  Have you tried benchmarking say, a dozen tests both ways and comparing the results?

Comment: @MattMorgan not yet. I asked this question hoping that somebody already did this or there is something in the documentation that I didn't find myself. Can't just start refactoring the project until I have at least some evidence that it's worth doing